# Generate HMAC-SHA256 Algorithm hash using JavaScript integration

Tags: javascript, qualtrics, hmacsha256

People coming into a Qualtrics survey are going to be assigned a Key and a Signature by our panel partner that we are going to be storing in embedded variables. We need to run the Key through the HMAC-SHA256 algorithm, store it as an additional embedded variable, and then make sure it matches the Signature they originally came in with.

I can take care of the matching part, I just don't know what the JavaScript code is to generate the new signature value and store it in another embedded variable.

Comment: browser or nodejs? Actually, doesn't matter, they both have `subtleCrypto` - use that